# How to perform operations when playing sound in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, avaudioplayer

I play a MP3 in my iPhone app using AVAudioPlayer; i need to perform some operations at certain times (say 30th seconds, 1 minute); is there a way to invoke callback functions based on mp3 playing time?

Comment: You will have to create such logic yourself. Use a timer, start/stop/restart that timer depending on the status of the playback (KVO on AVAudioPlayer properties).

Answer (score 8):

I believe the best solution is to start an `NSTimer` as you start the `AVAudioPlayer` playing. You could set the timer to fire every half second or so. Then each time your timer fires, look at the `currentTime` property on your audio player.

In order to do something at certain intervals, I'd suggest you kept an instance variable for the playback time from last time your timer callback was called. Then if you had passed the critical point between last callback and this, do your action.

So, in pseudocode, the timer callback:

1. Get the `currentTime` of your AVAudioPlayer
2. Check to see if `currentTime` is greater than `criticalPoint`
3. If yes, check to see if `lastCurrentTime` is less than `criticalPoint`
4. If yes to that too, do your action.
5. Set `lastCurrentTime` to `currentTime`

Comment: Sadly, `currentTime` is not KVO compliant, so a timer's your best bet.

Comment: Add KVO on the playback status for taking pausing / stalls into account by stopping / restarting the timer and this solution should be perfect.

Answer (score 5):

If you're able to use AVPlayer instead of AVAudioPlayer, you can set boundary or periodic time observers:

```
// File URL or URL of a media library item
AVPlayer *player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:url];        

CMTime time = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(30.0, 600);
NSArray *times = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSValue valueWithCMTime:time]];

id playerObserver = [player addBoundaryTimeObserverForTimes:times queue:NULL usingBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"Playback time is 30 seconds");            
}];

[player play];

// remove the observer when you're done with the player:
[player removeTimeObserver:playerObserver];
```

AVPlayer documentation:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 1):

I found [this link](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVAudioPlayer/currentTime) describing a property property which seems to indicate you can get the current playback time.

> If the sound is playing, currentTime is the offset of the current
>   playback position, measured in seconds from the start of the sound. If
>   the sound is not playing, currentTime is the offset of where playing
>   starts upon calling the play method, measured in seconds from the
>   start of the sound.
>
> By setting this property you can seek to a specific point in a sound
>   file or implement audio fast-forward and rewind functions.

To check the time and perform your action you can simply query it:

```
if (avAudioPlayerObject.currentTime == 30.0) //You may need a more broad check. Double may not be able to exactly represent 30.0s
{
    //Do Something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes Sure you can ...it's tricky i hope it works for you but it works for me ..

```
1- you play your mp3 file.
```

2- `[self performSelector:@selector(Operation:) withObject:Object afterDelay:30];`
then the function

```
-(void)Operation:(id)sender;
```

called; so you fired function after 30 second of mp3 file .. you can make many of function based on time you want..

3- there is other solution using timers

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0 target:self selector:@selector(CheckTime:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

it will fire function called Check Time

```
-(void)CheckTime:(id)sender{
   if (avAudioPlayerObject.currentTime == 30.0)
   {
       //Do Something
       //Fire and function call such
       [self performSelector:@selector(Operation:) withObject:Object]
   }
}
```

then you can change time interval you want and repeats is for you to control repeat this action every 5 seconds or not..
Hope that helpful..

Thanks

Comment: I don't think your first solution would work: What if I was to pause the playback of the audio file for 1 second after 10 seconds of playback and then resume. The timer would fire 1 second too early.

Comment: the second then should work but i though that the user did n't control the sound to pause or resume .. but if so you can use the second solution..

Answer (score 1):

with multithreading your goal is simple, just do like this :

```
1 :  in your main thread create a variable for storing time passed 
2 :  create new thread like "checkthread" that check each 30-20 sec(as you need)
3 :  if the time passed is what you want do the callback
```

Answer (score 1):

i think ,you want to play different sound-files after 30sec then use this code :

1) all sound-files put in Array and then retrieve from document directory

2)then try this:

```
-(IBAction)play_sound
{

    BackgroundPlayer=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:[Arr_tone_selected objectAtIndex:j]ofType:@"mp3"]]error:NULL];
    BackgroundPlayer.delegate=self;

    [BackgroundPlayer play];


}   


- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
    [BackgroundPlayer stop];
    j++;
    [self performSelector:@selector(play_sound) withObject:Object afterDelay:30];   
}
```

Comment: What if I was to pause the playback of the audio file for 1 second after 10 seconds of playback and then resume. The timer would fire 1 second too early.

Comment: your sound-file complete then automatically stop sound and after 30 sec play another sound-file ,in my above code...what u say i don't get clearly?

Comment: I think I've commented on the wrong answer, but I dont think you've understood the question. The "operation" the OP mentions could be any action, not just starting another sound. And what if the OP wants to play a track that is 45 seconds long, but still perform the action after 30s of playback. They dont mention the length of the track they wish to play